# Decomposition of $L^2(G)$ related to Peter Weyl Theorem involving induced representations

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $H$ a subgroup. In [The geometry of inequivalent quantizations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321391906092) (right under equation 2.11) the authors seem to claim that
$$
    L^2(G) = \bigoplus_{\mu \in \widehat{H}} d_\mu  Ind_H^G(\mu).
$$
Here $\widehat{H}$ is the set of irreps of $H$, $d_\mu$ is the dimension of the irrep, and $Ind_H^G(\mu)$ is the induced representation (space) of $\mu$.

How do you prove this claim?

Comment: Hmm, does $L^2(G)={\rm Ind}_H^GL^2(H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @elemelons response I think the following works.

Using properties (1) and (3) from [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InducedRepresentation.html), we can write
\begin{align}
L^2(G) &= \text{Ind}_{ \{e\} }^G( 1 ) \\
&= \text{Ind}_H^G\left( \text{Ind}_{ \{e\} }^H (1 ) \right) \\
&= \text{Ind}_H^G\left( L^2(H) \right) \\ 
&=\text{Ind}_H^G\left( \bigoplus_{\mu \in \widehat{H}} d_\mu V_\mu \right) \\ 
&= \bigoplus_{\mu \in \widehat{H}} d_\mu \text{Ind}_H^G\left(  V_\mu \right).
\end{align}

The penultimate line follows from the fact that the regular representation of a group $H$ can be split into a direct sum over irreps of $H$ with multiplicity equal to the dimension of the irrep.